# Performance penalty to repeatedly create Linq to SQL DataContext objects

Tags: linq-to-sql

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
       bar1();
       bar2();
    }

    private void bar1()
    {
        using (var dataContext = new SomeDataContext())
        {
            //do some query
        }
    }

    private void bar2()
    {
        using (var dataContext = new SomeDataContext())
        {
            //do some query
        }
    }
}
```

In the name of performance, should I consider:

```
class foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
        using (var dataContext = new SomeDataContext())
        {
            bar1(dataContext);
            bar2(dataContext);
        }
    }

    private void bar1(SomeDataContext dataContext)
    {         
    }

    //similar for bar2
}
```

Comment: You should be fine, creating the DataContext is not expensive.

Comment: If by query you mean only retrieval, no update/insert/delete you will be fine. In that case you can set EnableTrackChanges on the DC to false if you are very concerned about performance

Answer (score 0):

you should consider this tips:

1) your connection will be open until both `bar1` and `bar2` being complete.

2) if any exception occure in `bar1` that cause your connection being close you must open it in `bar2`. at least you need an `if` statement that check connection status.

creating new instance of data context almost always not a expensive job. you should first( and in best practice) tune your queries.

If I want to write code for scenario like your code I create instance in every method( for I do not have a relationship with the two methods) but like this:

```
class foo 
{ 
 var dataContext ;
public void bar() 
{ 
   bar1(); 
   bar2(); 
} 

private void bar1() 
{ 
    using (dataContext = new SomeDataContext()) 
    { 
        //do some query 
    } 
} 

    private void bar2() 
    { 
        using (dataContext = new SomeDataContext()) 
        { 
            //do some query 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I hope this help